# jasper report timezone issue in JS 5.1

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

In my jasperReport I have a input control of java.sql.Timestamp datatype.
Now using this input control user can select date before running the report.now when I copy the underline parameter of datepicker(input control) in the report , i get exact time in the report what user have selected .

My requirement is to format the date selected by the user.So I have written a simple function like

```
public static String convertDateToString(java.sql.Timestamp inputDate)
{
    System.out.println("The input Date is :: "+inputDate);
    String s = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.S").format(inputDate);
    System.out.println("The output Date is :: "+s);
    return s;
}
```

Now when the browser and jasperserver are in same timezone , this works fine but when 
the server is in different timezone , the input date is different from the printed date

Comment: you might what to read http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/timezones-jasperreports-server#Automatically_using_the_client-s_timezone

Comment: There are also the following built-in system parameter, ready to use in expressions: `$P{REPORT_TIME_ZONE}`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this i have used in iReport.

```
1:-Create a Parameter “DateFormatter” with 
   class="java.text.DateFormat" and set default value

  default value =[$P{REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY}.createDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 
    HH:mm",$P{REPORT_LOCALE}, java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"))
```

2:- Text filed expression:-

```
$F{ImportDate}== null ? "N/A" : $P{DateFormatter}.format($F{ImportDate})
```